# Создание посредством css вложенного подменю

Tags: css

[image: пример меню Css]

Каким образом посредством `css` можно создать меню аналогичное данной картинке?

Comment: у `ul` левый бордер. у `li` черточки абсолютно позиционированны через `:before` например

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-menu {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.b-menu * ul{
  list-style: none;
}
.b-menu > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  position: relative;
}
.b-menu > li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #222;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-] {
  display: none;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-] + label {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-] + label:hover{
  background: #111;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-]:checked + label{
  background: #000;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-] + label ~ [id^=submenu-] {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-] + label:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-color: #666 transparent transparent transparent;
   -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-]:checked + label:after{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-] + label:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  background: #619EF1;
   -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-menu > li [id^=m-]:checked + label:before{  
  width: 8px;  
}
.b-menu > li #m-1:checked + label ~ #submenu-1,
.b-menu > li #m-2:checked + label ~ #submenu-2,
.b-menu > li #m-3:checked + label ~ #submenu-3,
.b-menu > li #m-4:checked + label ~ #submenu-4{
  max-height: 300px;
}



.b-menu > li > ul {
  background: #222222;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.b-menu > li > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
.b-menu > li > ul > li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin-top: -0.5px;
}
.b-menu > li > ul > li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
}
.b-menu > li > ul > li:first-child:after {
  top: 50%;
}
.b-menu > li > ul > li:last-child:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 50%;
}
.b-menu > li > ul.submenu-one > li:first-child:after,
.b-menu > li > ul.submenu-one > li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.b-menu > li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-menu > li a > span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.b-menu > li a > span:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-menu > li a > span:hover:before{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b-menu">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="m" id="m-1" checked />
    <label for="m-1">Menu 1</label>
    <ul id="submenu-1">
    <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 1.1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 1.2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 1.3</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 1.4</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 1.5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="m" id="m-2" />
    <label for="m-2">Menu 2</label>
    <ul id="submenu-2">
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 2.1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 2.2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 2.3</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="m" id="m-3" />
    <label for="m-3">Menu 3</label>
    <ul id="submenu-3">
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 3.1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 3.2</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="m" id="m-4" />
    <label for="m-4">Menu 4</label>
    <ul id="submenu-4" class="submenu-one">
      <li><a href="#"><span>submenu 4.1</span></a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а как вы подобрали/угадали/поняли, что `.b-menu > li > ul > li:last-child:after` надо `top:auto` ?

Comment: При задании значения в процентах, положение элемента вычисляется в зависимости от высоты родительского элемента. При задании  top:auto - не меняеся положение элемента + добавляем bottom:50%(нужный нам отступ снизу);